# Нужна помощь с .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

```
  RewriteRule ^brands/$ catalog/brands/index.php [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^brands/(.*)/$ catalog/brands/letters.php/$1 [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^brands/(.*)/(.*)/$ catalog/brands/goods.php/$1&/$2 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^brands/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ catalog/brands/detail.php/$1&/$2/$3 [L,QSA]
```

Не срабатывает правило `RewriteRule ^brands/(.*)/(.*)/$ catalog/brands/goods.php/$1&/$2 [L,QSA]` -> `brands/b/bmv/` если два параметра, то должна открываться страница goods.php, но вместо этого открывается letters.php как будто я перехожу по `RewriteRule ^brands/(.*)/$ catalog/brands/letters.php/$1 [NC,L]`->  `brands/b/`

Помогите разобраться

Comment: Потому что `.*` обозначает ЛЮБОЙ символ — в том числе и слэш `/`, соответственно `brands/b/bmv/` отлично подходит под правило `^brands/(.*)/$`

Comment: Спасибо большое)